# How to use yaml-cpp in NS3

Tags: linker, build-automation, waf, ns-3

Does anyone know how to use the yaml-cpp lib in NS3 module?

I have finished the source code, but I have a hard time figuring out how to link it as it got the `undefined reference to` error when building with waf.

Comment: more info, try with ’-vvv’

Answer (score 0):

To use yaml-cpp you just have to write something like :

```
def options(opt):
    opt.load("cxx_compiler")

def configure(conf):
    conf.load("cxx_compiler")
    conf.check_cfg(package = "yaml-cpp", args = ["--cflags",  "--libs", ], uselib_store = "YAMLCPP")

def build(bld):
    bld.program(source = "main.cpp", use = "YAMLCPP")
```

waf use pkg-config to get all the options. Main is the source file using yaml-cpp.